# По каким запросам приходят на сайт. PHP

Tags: php

Необходимо с помощью PHP узнать по какому запросу из поисковика (яндекс/гугл) пришел посетитель на сайт.

Это возможно?

Comment: Я не эксперт, но, по крайней мере, это не звучит как нечто возможное

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте на Ваш сайт счётчики от Яндекса и Гугла. Они предоставят Вам статистику, в том числе по источникам трафика.

Answer (score 1):

Можете использовать глобальную переменную `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` - она предоставит вам `URL` с которого был произведен переход на текущую страницу. Дальше уже ваши варианты и решения как парсить из этой ссылки инфу потому что ссылка будет вида: `https://google.com/qwyeuiqwyeuqywei123123h12j3k1j2k3hkj123jkh1h23`

Answer (score -1):

Не думаю что можно, как вариант сделать небольшой словарь и посмотреть по каким вариантом ваш сайт есть в поисковике.

Comment: А, если основной трафик по запросам, которые в словарь не входят?